# IE8 CSS Text Spacing Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm running into a CSS text justify issue in ie8 and need to create a ie8 specific rule to address the issue, but haven't been able to figure it out.

The page & text is supposed to look like so: [**Link to Page**](http://tinyurl.com/d3va35m) (Use modern browser like Chrome / Safari / Firefox).

Img attached showing ie8 messed up spacing.[image]

**CSS**

```
/*Fancybox Gallery Divs*/


#thumbs {   
    width: 960px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

#thumbs a {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}

/*Descriptions*/


#desc-wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

.description {
    float:left;
    width: 320px; // Increase/decrease width for margin between images
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!--/ Photo Thumbs Row 1-->

<div id="thumbs">

<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/roscoes-run.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/roscoes-run(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/roscoes-run-2.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/roscoes-run-2(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/chicken-waffles.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/chicken-waffles(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>

<span class="stretch"></span>


</div>

<!--/ Description-->

<div id="desc-wrapper">
<div class="description">Roscoe's Run 2012</div>
<div class="description">Roscoe's Run 2012</div>
<div class="description">Roscoe's Run 2012</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>




<!--/ Photo Thumbs Row 2-->

<div id="thumbs">

<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/mens-retreat-2012.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/mens-retreat-2012(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/winter-retreat-2012.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/winter-retreat-2012(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/new-years-eve-2012.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/new-years-eve-2012(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>


<span class="stretch"></span>

</div>


<!--/ Description-->

<div id="desc-wrapper">
<div class="description">Men's Retreat 2012</div>
<div class="description">Winter Retreat 2012</div>
<div class="description">New Year's Eve 2012</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't know, if I understand it right. You want the description with a center alignment? I've checked it in IE8 with the built-in development tools. If you remove the 

    `#desc-wrapper {
        text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    }` .. after removing this in the dev tool, it looks okay in IE8 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is:

```
text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
```

on the #desc-wrapper (which, by the way, is a repeated ID, this should be a class). Either remove it from both media.css and media-ie8.css (not sure why it's necessary) or override it in media-ie8.css to auto. Seriously, though, it's an IE-only property. Just remove it?

Comment: Thank you both for the replies, I checked in the IE8 Developer tools as mentioned, & it works when in the browser tools, but not when I update the CSS file, do you see anything else that might also cause this?

Comment: Thanks, got it updated, had to delete two lines total to make it work:
-ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
text-justify: distribute-all-lines;

Answer (score 0):

well, you need to add a conditional comment as your ie-css is being overridden by the regular media.css

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
your stuff
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I've updated the CSS in "media-ie8.css" and still no dice, this is a weird issue. Thank you for your help!